mlrMBO Optimizing the noisy function
I'm trying to find the minimum of an unknown noisy multivariate function. For clarity, let's take a simple case.
set.seed(5)
s <- sin(0.5 * seq(0,10,0.1) + 5)/-1
ln <- as.numeric(length(s))
sn <- s + rnorm(ln,sd = 0.3)


plot(sn,t="l", col=8,lty=2)
lines(s, col=4)
points(which.min(s), min(s), lwd=5 , col=4)


The blue dot is the value I'm trying to get.
My objective function here is to find the index of the point that corresponds to the minimum of the non-noisy function.
fit <- function(i) sn[ round(i,0) ] 

Here is the code that I practically copied from this example
library(mlrMBO)
obj.fun = makeSingleObjectiveFunction(name = "noisy_fu", 
                                      fn = fit, 
                                      has.simple.signature = TRUE, 
                                      par.set = makeNumericParamSet("i",
                                                                    len = 1, 
                                                                    lower = 1, 
                                                                    upper = length(sn)),
                                      noisy = TRUE)

ctrl = makeMBOControl(final.method = "best.predicted", final.evals = 10)
ctrl = setMBOControlInfill(ctrl, crit = crit.eqi)
ctrl = setMBOControlTermination(ctrl, iters = 10)

configureMlr(on.learner.warning = "quiet", show.learner.output = FALSE)
res = mbo(obj.fun, control = ctrl, show.info = T)

points(res$x, res$y, lwd=5 , col=3)

I made several runs and I'm not very happy with the result

Can I change something in my code so that the spread becomes smaller and the points are closer to the real minimum, which is indicated by the blue dot?
====UPD==== for datawookie
The function s, sn is unknown by default, otherwise we don't need optimization. If the function were known, then all the code for finding the minimum would look like this
set.seed(5)
s <- sin(0.5 * seq(0,10,0.1) + 5)/-1
ln <- as.numeric(length(s))
sn <- s + rnorm(ln,sd = 0.3)

which.min(s)

also my real function is multidimensional, I mentioned this at the very beginning

Not sure what your question is -- if you optimize a noisy version of the function, you can't expect to identify the true underlying optimum.

Well, the model should look for something like the minimum of the moving average, well, definitely not local minima.
It seems to me

The model is not returning local minima. Look at the first and fourth green dots (counting from left). Neither of these is a local minimum. I think that there's a misunderstanding around what the mlrMBO package is actually doing here.

The example you give is quite different from the example you linked. In the linked example, the noise is applied at function call, so each time fun is called by the optimizer, it generates new noise. In contrast, your fit function is deterministic: the same i will always result in the same output value. Try changing it to fit <- function(x) rnorm(x, 0, 0.3) - sin(x/20 + 5).

I think I understand what you are talking about, I need to add new noise every time to the fitness function, but I’m still not entirely sure that this is true. Can you show me specifically using my example how to do this correctly?

You mention finding the minimum of the moving average in the comments, so how about simply optimising a smoothed version of the data?

Create the sample data.

set.seed(13)

x <- seq(0, 10, 0.1)
s <- sin(0.5 * x + 5) / -1
sn <- s + rnorm(length(s), sd = 0.3)

plot(sn, t="l", col=8,lty=2)
lines(s, col=4)
points(which.min(s), min(s), lwd=5 , col=4)


Smooth.

smoothed <- lowess(x, sn, f = 0.3)
lines(smoothed$y, col = "blue")


Optimise.

library(mlrMBO)

fit <- function(i) smoothed$y[ round(i,0) ] 

obj.fun = makeSingleObjectiveFunction(
  name = "noisy_fu", 
  fn = fit, 
  has.simple.signature = TRUE, 
  par.set = makeNumericParamSet(
    "i",
    len = 1, 
    lower = 1, 
    upper = length(sn)
  ),
  noisy = TRUE
)

ctrl = makeMBOControl(final.method = "best.predicted", final.evals = 10)
ctrl = setMBOControlInfill(ctrl, crit = crit.eqi)
ctrl = setMBOControlTermination(ctrl, iters = 10)

configureMlr(on.learner.warning = "quiet", show.learner.output = FALSE)
res = mbo(obj.fun, control = ctrl, show.info = T)

points(res$x, res$y, lwd=5 , col=3)

The calculated minimum is close to the expected location and is IMHO pretty reasonable given that you are optimising noisy data.
There are various approaches to smoothing the data, but lowess() is a good start. You can adjust the smoother span to make it more/less smooth.
With this approach you can probably use a less sophisticated optimiser than mlrMBO too.

It might also be worthwhile considering that, due to the way that your objective function is formulated (fit <- function(i) sn[round(i,0)]) this is what you are effectively optimising:

My understanding of your problem is that you have some noisy (multivariate/multidimensional) data and you want to find the minimum it. However, you want to find the minimum of the underlying function and not the noisy data. So my suggestion is to smooth the noisy data and then optimise the smoothed data.

That is, I don’t understand how to apply your example

"function s, sn is unknown by default". Yes, I realise that. This is replicated in Step 1 of my answer. Step 2 does smoothing on those results and doesn't make any assumptions about the underlying function. It's simply smoothing the data.

"also my real function is multidimensional". I appreciate that. However, the question is posed as a univariate optimisation problem.

It seems to me that this does not change anything in this matter except the complexity of the explanation
